# GoogleMapsSDK : Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, linker-errors, google-maps-sdk-ios, undefined-symbol

I am trying to install the Google maps SDK and I am running through this error when running:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey", referenced from:
      -[GMSx_PEBeaconScanner centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:] in GoogleMaps(PEBeaconScanner.o)
  "_CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey", referenced from:
      -[GMSx_PEBeaconScanner centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:] in GoogleMaps(PEBeaconScanner.o)
  "_CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey", referenced from:
      -[GMSx_PEBeaconScanner scanIfAppropriate] in GoogleMaps(PEBeaconScanner.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CBCentralManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleMaps(PEBeaconScanner.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CBUUID", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleMaps(PEBeacon.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleMaps(PEBeaconScanner.o)
  "_vImageBoxConvolve_Planar8", referenced from:
      (anonymous namespace)::CreateBlurredImage(CGImage*, double, double) in GoogleMaps(GLWaterGroup.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 46):

I noticed the following changes when I upgraded an app that was using the older Google maps SDK that had been installed manually:

- Need to link to **CoreBluetooth.framework** and **Accelerate.framework** in Build Phases -> Link Bundle with Libraries.
- The **-all_load** flag under "Other Linker Flags" will cause "duplicate symbol" errors.  (Use **-ObjC** instead.)

If you use the CocoaPods method of installation (per their current instructions), it should take of the required frameworks but it'll still get messed up by **-all_load**.

Comment: this saves my time a lot.. +1 for this one.

Comment: Why cant Google Document this!  Thank you my friend!

Answer (score 11):

make sure following are included

***GoogleMaps SDK framework and bundle***

GoogleMaps (with .framework extension) is present at your root directory (where your .xcodeproj is)

GoogleMaps (with .bundle extension) is referenced in your xcode project

***Following Frameworks***

Accelerate.framework

AVFoundation.framework

CoreBluetooth.framework

CoreData.framework

CoreGraphics.framework

CoreLocation.framework

CoreText.framework

GLKit.framework

ImageIO.framework

libc++.dylib

libicucore.dylib

libz.dylib

OpenGLES.framework

QuartzCore.framework

Security.framework

SystemConfiguration.framework

***Build Settings***

*Architecture value* in your project settings includes armv7.

*Other Linker Flags* has -ObjC , if not present add it

Comment: what if I can't use the -ObjC flag? I need it for google maps but it causes conflicts with parse framework. any help? Using -force_load causes symbol duplicates...

Comment: This answer fixed my issue with https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps cordova plugin which uses google maps IOS sdk 2.0.1 (at the time of writing).

Answer (score 9):

```
**_vImageBoxConvolve_Planar8, referenced from: (anonymous namespace)::CreateBlurredImage(CGImage*, double, double) in GoogleMaps(GLWaterGroup.o)**

This required "Accelerate.framework". So, please add it.

Steps:
1)Build Phases -> Link Bundle with Libraries.
2)Click "+",
3)Select "Accelerate.framework". Finish.

===================================

Others errors required "CoreBluetooth.framework. So, please add it also in similar way.
```

Comment: you made my day Arun +1

Comment: This is also the solution if you are removing Google maps from your app except you do the "-"

Answer (score 5):

It looks like Google's API needs CoreBluetooth for Beacon location. Link against `CoreBluetooth.framework` in your build phases and everything should be fine.

[image]

**EDIT:**
Make sure to install GoogleMaps through those instructions to avoid any issue: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start

Comment: Thank you Quentin.

I just did that and unfortunately it sent another error:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_vImageBoxConvolve_Planar8", referenced from:
      (anonymous namespace)::CreateBlurredImage(CGImage*, double, double) in GoogleMaps(GLWaterGroup.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: You should follow those instructions to make sure that everything you need is installed: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start

Comment: Yeah those instructions suck IMO, nowhere does it mention CoreBluetooth there.

Comment: So it looks like _vImageBoxConvolve_Planar8 is available in Accelerate.framework.  I added that to my project, and the problem went away, now it complains GoogleMaps.framework defines 706 duplicate symbols :(

Comment: That's why you should undo everything and install it through Cocoapods. It will take care of every dependencies.

Comment: I added `CoreBluetooth`  & `Accelerate` and everything worked fine (I'm using Pods too).

Comment: I have the same problem than funkybro, I now have 706 duplicates. can't use cocoa pods (cause it mess everything up, or -ObjC flag...

Answer (score 2):

I am having same problem, in my case I am having 2 reference of GoogleMap.framework, I deleted old framework reference and problem get solved :)

- Click on project
- In **Build Phases** -> **Link Binary With Libraries** -> Check any duplicate reference is present for GoogleMaps.framework
- If yes then delete one, which you not added.

Comment: Thanks! checking duplicate references has helped me!

Answer (score 2):

```
**_vImageBoxConvolve_Planar8, referenced from: (anonymous namespace)::CreateBlurredImage(CGImage*, double, double) in GoogleMaps(GLWaterGroup.o)**

This required "Accelerate.framework". So, please add it.

Steps:
1)Build Phases -> Link Bundle with Libraries.
2)Click "+",
3)Select "Accelerate.framework". Finish.
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing **-all_load** flag from (Targets->Build Settings->Other linker flag) resolved my issue while using cocoa pods.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is experiencing this today, Linking `CoreLocation.framework` binary in **Build Settings** did the trick for me