# Linker command failed with exit code 1 on my Swift app

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, compiler-errors

Can't figure this out. Tried making a completely new project and it still doesn't work. This app uses GoogleMaps. Error below:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey", referenced from:
>         -[GMSx_PEBeaconScanner centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:] in
>   GoogleMaps(PEBeaconScanner.o)   "_CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey",
>   referenced from:
>         -[GMSx_PEBeaconScanner centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:] in
>   GoogleMaps(PEBeaconScanner.o)
>   "_CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey", referenced from:
>         -[GMSx_PEBeaconScanner scanIfAppropriate] in GoogleMaps(PEBeaconScanner.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CBCentralManager",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in GoogleMaps(PEBeaconScanner.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CBUUID", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in GoogleMaps(PEBeacon.o)
>         objc-class-ref in GoogleMaps(PEBeaconScanner.o)   "_vImageBoxConvolve_Planar8", referenced from:
>         (anonymous namespace)::CreateBlurredImage(CGImage*, float, float) in GoogleMaps(GLWaterGroup.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for
>   architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
>   (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try importing CoreBluetooth.framework and Accelerate.framework. Also use "-ObjC" instead of "-all_load" in under "Other Linker Flags".

You can refer colink's reply in [GoogleMapsSDK : Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712852/googlemapssdk-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)

Comment: dammmmnnnn..this really saved me.!