# Undefined symbols for architecture "_OBJC_CLASS_$_IMACompanionAdSlot"

Tags: swift, tvos, undefined-symbol, google-ima

This target is tvOS. I'm using Cocoapods and here is the pod

```
pod 'GoogleAds-IMA-tvOS-SDK', '4.3.2'
```

I've tried updating to a more recent version, but the issue remained.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_IMACompanionAdSlot", referenced from:
        objc-class-ref in DAILinearTVPlayer.o
        objc-class-ref in NativePlayer.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

This is the error I get when I try to build my target with `SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = "-Onone"`.

When I change only the optimization level to `SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = "-O"` build is successful.

I've tried most of the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712852/googlemapssdk-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64) and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408531/xcode-build-failure-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64) but nothing worked in my case.

When I try to build for simulator I get the same error except "... for architecture x86_64"

Comment: did u check  supported arch for GoogleAds-IMA-tvOS-SDK ?

Comment: Couldn't find any docs describing supported arch. But I can build my target successfully if I turn optimisation on so I guess this is not a supported arch issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using wrong init for IMAAdDisplayContainer

```
IMAAdDisplayContainer(adContainer: self.view, viewController: self, companionSlots: nil)
```

companion slots aren't supported on tvOS [here is comment about this](https://groups.google.com/g/ima-sdk/c/1H6fn8WvWsY/m/YeP6jd90AAAJ).
After I've changed init to

```
IMAAdDisplayContainer(adContainer: self.view, viewController: self)
```

Everything compiled successfully in Debug configuration and without optimizations. Finally I can use debugger normally again!

Answer (score 0):

TARGET -> Build Settings, search 'VALID'. Set VALID_ARCHS. If run with a simulator set x86_64 else iPhone device set arm64.

This is work for me. You can try.

Comment: I don't have this settings in Build Settings for my target. I've tried searching for VALID, ARCH, valid etc. I have something in Architectures -> Architectures -> $(ARCH_STANDARD) but I think it's a different settings from the one you've mentioned.