# Can't solve this clang error - ios

Tags: ios, xcode6, clang

**Error message:**

```
Clang error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Searched lot and..

**I have done:**

- Checked  "Compile Sources" section in "Build Phases" for any duplicate .m files there.
- Checked my resources for any duplicate files.
- Removed the derived data `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

  But no use...!!!

**If iam attaching the error log completely,is there any way to identify from it**, please check it, struggling to find out the issue. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Try to add TestFlight Framework..

Comment: @SidShah : and i have got this error. check new image.

Comment: Thats the google framework error.Follow this link and add required frameworks : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027229/apple-mach-o-linker-error-when-using-google-maps-sdk-for-ios

Comment: @SidShah: Thanks man. But same error repeats.

Comment: happen sometimes for me. i think this is xcode bug, check all ur framework for any errror, and recompile all of them seperatly. and re add framework. maybe after clean up change the framework location

Comment: are you tried to run simulator , run in device it does not show the error

Answer (score 1):

Look carefully at the "directory not found" errors!

Among other things you have directory names with an embedded space: "Reach Me" and "Third Party" that is incorrectly quoted in the Library search paths. In general embedded spaces in file and directory names can cause quoting problems are are best avoided.

It seems there is a library path: "/Users/alisons/Downloads/Reach Me/Reach Me/Classes/Third Party"

Rename the library and put in a directory in the project file hierarchy, just leaving it in the Downloads directory is just going to cause problems.